# Kotlin - Can't assign new values to lateinit vars via Destructuring Declaration

Tags: kotlin

The following Kotlin code works

```
val (x, y) = getSomeXYPair()
```

But you can't do this with `lateinit` global vars

```
class Foo {

    private lateinit var x: Int
    private lateinit var y: Int

    init {
        (x, y) = getSomeXYPair()
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering if I'm either doing something wrong, or this just isn't supported in Kotlin?

Comment: This could work for python-like language`a = None; b = None; (a, b) = 5, 6; print(a, b);`, but it's not implemented  in Kotlin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it with any type of variables, local or not:

```
fun main() {
    var x : Int = 1
    var y : Int = 2

    (x, y) = getSomeXYPair()
}
```

This syntax is simply invalid in Kotlin. You're required to start destructuring declaration with either `var` or `val`:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations

That is, putting aside the fact that `lateinit` is not supported on primitive types such as `Int`.

Comment: A destructuring declaration does not always have to start with `var` or `val`: if you destructure a lambda parameter for example `(1 to 2).let { (key, value) -> key + value }`.